# Cannot connect to to site - FTP timeout

Tags: ftp, whm, filezilla

not sure where to ask this question so I figured I would try here to see if there's anyone that can help.

I have an FTP connection where I have the correct ftp information, but the FTP always seems to get hung up on the connection, then eventually hung up in filezilla.

I have the WHM information to this client's server, but I just don't know what I would need to set the ftp settings to in order to fix this?  I'm basically a front-end developer needing to do a few mobile updates so Idon't really know much about server configuration.

In filezilla, this is the last part it gets hung up on:

Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode 
Command:    MLSD

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this in WHM?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (flag it for moderator attention). It's off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else has this same issue, just set the ftp mode to "active"